# How to position images as a grid in a page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I was trying to position images as shown in the figure in LaTeX, need help.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452773/47927 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91348/47927. Also, this might be interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407619/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `subcaption` package and arrange the images using a `tabluar`. The following may be a starting point. It is not exactly semantically correct though, because from your example it seems that both, Image and Residual, should belong to the same subfigure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\subfigwidth}
\setlength{\subfigwidth}{20mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Image type}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth}}

Image & 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{I32}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{DIP TV}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{DIP}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{sst}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} \\

Residual & 
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-b}

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{r p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth} p{\subfigwidth}}

Image & 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{gst}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{est}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{mst}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigwidth}
    \caption{est}
    \includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{subfigure} \\

Residual & 
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\subfigwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]